# AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned

Tags: apache-2.4

We are in midst of using the httpd server exclusively for all our application and we are facing the below issue.

Every now and then we get this error in the error.log :

```
[Mon Mar 22 07:33:34.544296 2021] [proxy:error] [pid 2640] [client 10.249.1.4:57938] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /GenericSolrServer/select, referer:
```

And user will have to re-do the operations again.

I have done following this so far :

```
KeepAlive On
Timeout 900
KeepAliveTimeout 30
```

in httpd.conf

```
SetEnv proxy-initial-not-pooled 1
SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1
```

Please let me know if you can help me out on this at priority please.

Comment: What webserver are you using?

Comment: @bjoster it looks like apache

Comment: oh and it's tagged!